# I need help about list index out of range

Tags: python, scrapy

Basically the concept of my project is to scrape emails by reading a csv file and that file contains about 200 urls and from that (csv) file I want to scrape all emails against these urls.
But I am facing a issue is indexing error

The error is

```
/home/jawad/PycharmProjects/beautifulsoup/venv/bin/python /home/jawad/Pycharm/pycharm-community-2021.1/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 42197 --file /home/jawad/PycharmProjects/beautifulsoup/emailhunter/emailhunter/spiders/emailscrapping.py
Connected to pydev debugger (build 211.6693.115)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jawad/PycharmProjects/beautifulsoup/emailhunter/emailhunter/spiders/emailscrapping.py", line 7, in <module>
    a= line[0].split('\t')[4]
IndexError: list index out of range
python-BaseException
```

And my python code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re
import csv
with open('Clients.csv','r', encoding="utf16", errors='ignore') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        a= line[0].split('\t')[4]
        print(a)
        # for url in a:

        def get_email(a):
            response = requests.get(a, headers={
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36',
                'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 'x-runtime': '148ms'}, allow_redirects=True).content

            soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
            email = soup(text=re.compile(r'[A-Za-z0-9\.\+_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]*'))

            _emailtokens = str(email).replace("\\t", "").replace("\\n", "").split(' ')

            if len(_emailtokens):
                print([match.group(0) for token in _emailtokens for match in
                       [re.search(r"([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)", str(token.strip()))] if
                       match])

    get_email(a)
```

Comment: I think you should print your line[0] and see how many `\t` exist in it, because this error is telling you that there are not 5 (0 to index 4). If there are only 4, then index at 3 because that is the 4th when you count from zero.

Comment: Sir i tried that already.Same error.

Comment: Can you share the output when you print line[0] before doing .split()?

Comment: I want to read my referring domains which are following at 4,means Line: ['domain rating','Aherf rank','referring page count','referring domains','last check','last seen'].Now at 4 where i put all my url's.

Comment: Is that the output when you print the .split()? I know what you are trying to do, but you need to take the line that has the error and do one thing at a time. First call line[0] and see if that works, then next line do split() and see if that works, then [4] on that. There is an error there so best way to know why is to break it down into small pieces and do one step at a time.

Comment: so when i print only line[0] i.e a=line[0] and then print(a). and debug it.its working fine.

Comment: Ok, so that means it's after that step. When you do a=line[0].split('\t') and print(a) can you share that exact output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When indexing a list, you should always either catch `IndexError` in a **'try - except'** block, or check to see if that index is in range prior (unless you are handling the `IndexError` in the calling function, or one of its 'parents').

For debugging purposes, I would try one of the following:

```
try:
    print("Line = {}".format(line))
    print("Line[0] = {}".format(line[0]))
    print("Split line = {}".format(line[0].split('\t'))
    print("5th element = {}".format(line[0].split('\t')[4])
    a = line[0].split('\t')[4]
except IndexError as e:
    print("Index Error: {}".format(e))
```

```
print("Line = {}".format(line))
correct = True
if len(line) > 0:
    print("Line[0] = {}".format(line[0]))
else:
    print("Line length = {}".format(len(line))
    correct = False
print("Split line = {}".format(line[0].split('\t'))
if len(line) > 5:
    print("5th element = {}".format(line[0].split('\t')[4])
else:
    print("Only {} elements in tab split list".format(len(line[0].split('\t')))
    correct = False
if correct:
    a = line[0].split('\t')[4]
else:
    raise IndexError
```